# How to make characters displayed correctly when sending email with chilkat?

Tags: go, chilkat, chilkat-email

I use chilkat 9.5.0.80.

The problem is that some characters in email appear wrong. For example this `è` appears as `Ã¨` in the inbox mailbox. I expect it to be displayed as I set it - `è`.

This is the minimal reproducible code:

```
email := chilkat.NewEmail()
email.SetCharset("utf-8")
email.AddTo("", toEmail)
email.SetSubject("test")
email.SetHtmlBody("è")
mailMan := chilkat.NewMailMan()
mailMan.SetSmtpHost(host)
mailMan.SetSmtpPort(25)
mailMan.SetSmtpUsername(username)
mailMan.SetSmtpPassword(password)
mailMan.SendEmail(email)
```

Also I noticed that the header of html body part in different smtp servers mime appears different.
First is displayed correctly and looks like:

```
--------------050209010604000502060206
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

And second is wrong, looks like:

```
--------------030709010607010008060507
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The charset is different..

I think if I would set the html body as base64 it will displayed correct. But I have not found such possibility in chilkat...

Also tried with valid html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
è
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a clear [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Don't ask how to send base64-encoded emails. Ask how to solve your _actual problem_ of broken characters. Update your question with a actual code as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and show the actual output you receive, and what you expect instead.

Comment: @Flimzy, just few minutes, will be done

Comment: Did you try setting the character set to something that supports your characters, such as UTF-8? https://www.example-code.com/golang/email_charset.asp

Comment: @Flimzy yes I tries `email.SetCharset("utf-8")`

Comment: And no improvement?

Comment: For `HtmlBody` it might also be useful to use actual HTML, which specifies the character set.  i.e. `email.SetHtmlBody("<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/>...")`

Comment: @Flimzy No, still displayed wrong

Comment: How are you displaying it? i.e. which mail client or other tool?

Comment: @Flimzy. in my htnl string I have the following tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and displayed wrong

Comment: Only that your body is not valid html...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, html body is correct, it is just one char `"è"`. Problem is that on some smtp servers it is displayed correctly and on other not correct.

Comment: `email.SetHtmlBody("è")` does not look like this would create valid HTML to me...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, I updated the post, sure I tried with full valid html, it doesn't matter, is not displayed correctly on some smtp servers..

Answer (score 1):

I was right when I asked in my question, how to set html body as base64 with chilkat ? Because the following code shows special characters correctly on some smtp servers, but on some servers they are displayed wrong:

```
email := chilkat.NewEmail()
email.SetCharset("utf-8")
email.AddTo("", toEmail)
email.SetSubject("test")
email.SetHtmlBody("è")
mailMan := chilkat.NewMailMan()
mailMan.SetSmtpHost(host)
mailMan.SetSmtpPort(25)
mailMan.SetSmtpUsername(username)
mailMan.SetSmtpPassword(password)
mailMan.SendEmail(email)
```

The next solution allows to set and send html body mime part as base64, and it is displayed correctly on different smtp servers:

```
email := chilkat.NewEmail()
part := chilkat.NewMime()
part.SetBodyFromEncoded("base64", 
base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(bodyContent)))
part.SetContentType("text/html")
part.SetCharset("UTF-8")
email.SetFromMimeText(*part.GetMime())
```

Then you can set other fields to `email` object such as subject etc..